# How to do screen recording?

Tags: screenshot

I want to record screen of my laptop (HP Probook 4540s) which have windows 8.1(x64) and 1792 MB graphics manufactured by Intel. I have tried with VLC Media Player but it stops working when I start recording. I can record it with Microsoft Office Powerpoint 2016, but it will not help me in some cases... So please anyone help me.

Answer (score 2):

There is some tools like snagit you can record your screen via it, like that too many apps you can find it on internet... and if it doesn't help try it. Is is too easy than it...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83 here how to make a presentation as video.